# visual studio 2010 c++ load time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This is probably way too vague for any concrete answers, but this issue has been bothering me so I figured I'd give it a shot here:

Every time I hit F5 to run a project (and I'm talking something tiny 2 - 3 source files), first of all half the time it tells me that I need to rebuild the project even if the only change I made was add a breakpoint and then takes maybe ~20s to actually get the program running. This is a very basic command-line program and with gcc everything happens much, much faster. Any ideas?

PM

Comment: +1.  Not sure if this belongs on SO, or if it is off-topic, but I have had a similar experience in several projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long waiting time before VS actually starts the application when hitting F5 occurs in VS 2008 as well. The simple solution to that is to delete the .suo file. I don't know if VS 2010 uses .suo files, but at least it's something you can try.

Comment: it does, I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

When using VS2010 on older operating systems (Like WinXP), then one should make sure to install latest UIA (Windows Automation) component [MS KB971513](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971513/). Failing to do this will cause VS2010 to perform poorly.

Also check [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/15/patch-for-vs-2010-scrolling-context-menu.aspx) for other important hotfixes

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the case, but I remember VS used to act like this when I had lots of breakpoints.

Comment: Thta's quite likely. Visual Studio implements breakpoints by copying the orginal code, then overwriting it with `INT 3` instructions. Writing to code segments is tricky in DEP-enabled systems and probably causes quite a few cache flushes.